# Storing Grid State per User and storing serverside - EXT GWT

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

So I have been looking around the interwebs on how to store an EXT paging grid state on my server so that when users login back in their grid it is how they saved it.

I found this http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?64688-How-can-i-save-Grid-state-using-GXT but it is an old and dead thread.

What I have right now is:

grid.getState() returns a map of all col sizes, sorts, and hidden fields.

here is an example dumped to string:

{offset=0, limit=25, widthfieldname1=161, widthfield2=110, hiddenfield3=true }

I could store these key/values in a simple table with fields (username, key, value) and recreate this map and pass it to the front end.

So here is my question:

Does anyone have a code example of a full implementation of storing, retrieving and apply a grid state for GXT 2.4?

If not. How would I go about implementing one? I am confident i could store the state map in the database or XML. I am lost on how to apply this to a new session. How do i apply this state map to a new grid?

Comment: To clarify, are you talking about Ext JS or GXT? You've tagged Ext, but there's no Ext 2.4.

Comment: Hey a comment! Sorry, bad tag. I am referring to Sencha Ext GWT 2.2.4. I guess they renamed it GXT in version 3.x. But this is the java GWT library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**State management** is already build into many components, and also into grids.
Default GXT implementation uses Cookies (take a look at the `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.state.CookieProvider`) to store Grid's state, you just need make the grid statefull and give it a unique stateId:

```
grid.setStateful(true);
grid.setStateId("myGridUniqueId");
```

If **other** storage is required, then you need to extend `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.state.Provider`, implement you store/load logic and then pass it to `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.state.StateManager`, it's going to be pretty straightforward:

```
public static class MyProvider extends Provider {

    @Override
    protected void clearKey(String name) {
        // clearing logic
    }

    @Override
    protected String getValue(String name) {
        // read logic
    }

    @Override
    protected void setValue(String name, String value) {
        // store logic
    }
}

StateManager.get().setProvider(new MyProvider());
```

Please also note that State Management [is changed](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-gwt-3-0-state-api) in GXT3, you should keep it in mind if you need to migrate to 3.0 at the nearest future.